# How can I use a mutable variable in a plotchar function call?

Tags: pine-script

```
fix() => 
    summary_text = ""
    if barstate.islast
        Win_T_Percentage = 0
        Loss_T_Percentage = 0
        Total_Profit_Points = 0
        Total_T = Win_Trades + Loss_Trades

        if (Total_T != 0.0) 
            T_Trades  = floor(Total_T)
            Win_T_Percentage   = ceil(100.0 * (Win_Trades / Total_T))
            Loss_T_Percentage  = floor(100.0 * (Loss_Trades / Total_T))
            Total_Profit_Points = (Profit_Points - Loss_Points)

            summary_text :=("\nWinning Trades: " + nz(Win_T_Percentage,0) + "% (" + nz(Win_Trades,0) + " of " + nz(T_Trades,0) + ") \n" + "Losing Trades: " + nz(Loss_T_Percentage,0) + "% (" +nz(Loss_Trades,0) + " of " + nz(T_Trades,0) + ") \n" + "Green Points: +" + nz(Total_Profit_Points,0) + " pts \n")
    summary_text   



plotchar(barstate.islast, text =fix(), color = black,location = location.top)
```

If I run this I will get an error

> Output ... depends on a mutable variable.. please enclose variable in
>   a function call.

It fails at `plotchar` and because text is set to a mutable string. However, using a function is supposed to fix it. It did not.
Do you know any other solution?

Comment: You cannot do that.

Comment: Can't be done in pine script, some functions are just hardcoded to not take dynamic values.

Comment: That's because pine v.3 doesn't have series strings.

Comment: Will v4 solve this?

Comment: @Aftershock No, v4 didn't solve that unfortunately